# Obb file location after download from Google Play

Tags: java, android

https://github.com/danikula/Google-Play-Expansion-File/blob/master/expansion/src/main/java/com/google/android/vending/expansion/downloader/Helpers.java

expects obb data in different folders depending on api version:

```
static public String getSaveFilePath(Context c) {
        File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        String path = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 ? Constants.EXP_PATH_API23 : Constants.EXP_PATH;
        return root.toString() + path + c.getPackageName();
    }
```

Build.VERSION.SDK_INT is 23 for all my apps. 
Some of my apps have obb files in 
Android/data, some in
Android/obb 
after downloading from goolge play. How does play store decide where to store?